# Short Story or Book set in the post-nuclear world where main character finds the sun in a clearing after a journey during nuclear winter?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this a while ago in 8th grade and theres a guy and he goes on a quest to find the sun on a motorcycle I think and then he finds someone in a city that takes him to their house in a forest and then the sun shines and he farms and stuff. Please help, thanks!

Comment: This is incredibly broad. Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: This would benefit from taking a look at the guide above and adding in some more plot details, when you read it and anything else you can remember.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be **[Searching for Summer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18364428-searching-for-summer)** by Joan Aitken?

You can read the full story online [here](http://mrkingrocks.com/files/searching_for_summer.pdf). It's actually about a couple that go looking for the sun to celebrate their honeymoon. They travel around a post-apocalyptic Britain on a scooter and eventually find someone in the city that directs them to a small house in the forest where they see the sun and harvest some beans.

> *At least, he thought, they had left the golden place undisturbed. Mr.
>   Noakes never went into the wood. And they had done what they intended;
>   they had found the sun. Now they, too, would be able to tell their
>   grandchildren, when beginning a story, “Long, long ago, when we were
>   young, in the days when the sky was blue . . .*

Comment: What search term did you use to find this? I spent a reasonable amount of time searching.

Comment: I used quote marks to search for specific phrases; [post apocalyptic novel "find the sun" and "motorcycle"] which led me to [this page](https://prezi.com/u10ecokfitdh/elements-of-fiction/) which then led me to the answer

Comment: When I quoted "find sun" I got some very weird results

Comment: @Valorum Want to edit that info into your answer? I think it's really helpful to show people *how* you found their story as well as just giving them the answer, a la "teach a man to fish".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's more of a comment.

Comment: @Valorum I think it'd be a useful addition to your answer. Comments are transitory, but the precise search terms used to solve a question are going to be useful for anyone else trying to learn Google-fu for story-ID.